# Append the string to the v-bind: value

Tags: vue.js

In vue.js, I have a template like bellow:

```
<template v-for="(item,index) in menuList">
  <MenuItem v-if="item.children.length<=1" class='child' :name="item.children[0].name" :key="item.path">
....
```

you see the `:key="item.path"`, I want to add the `index` of the `v-for="(item,index) in menuList"` to be like bellow:

```
:key="/abc-1"
```

How to do with it? I want to append the index after the `item.path`.

Comment: what is the data of your `menuList`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might wanna try "Template Literals"

```
:key="`${item.path}-${index}`"
```

Here is more detail.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals